# Unexpected string length when using strlen in php

Tags: php, strlen, string-length

I am stuck with the issue as currently the result is quite unexpected. I am calculating a hashed keyword length and it is surely giving me an unexpected result.

```
echo strlen("$2a$08$MphfRBNtQMLuNro5HOtw3Ovu20cLgC0VKjt6w7zrKXfj1bv8tNnNa");
```

Output - `6`

Let me know the reason for this and why it is outputting `6` as a result.

Codepad Link - http://codepad.org/pLARBx6F

Comment: Your string is double-quoted.

Comment: @cHao ok..got it but how 6 ? the result

Comment: try this :echo strlen('$2a$08$MphfRBNtQMLuNro5HOtw3Ovu20cLgC0VKjt6w7zrKXfj1bv8tNnNa');

it takes parameter to a function as php variable and throws notice as variable not defined

Comment: `echo` or `var_dump` your string.  The reason should become clearer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use single quotes `'`. With the double quotes (`"`), due to the `$` in your string, parts of it get interpreted as variables.

Generally, it's not a bad idea to get accustomed to using single quotes unless you specifically need doubles.

Look at the "variables" contained here. They would be `$2a`, `$08`, and `$MphfRBNtQM......`
The first two couldn't be variables as they start with a number, thus, the 6 characters. The third one indeed could be a proper variable, but since it isn't set, it's empty.

Comment: Look at the "variables" contained here. They would be `$2a`, `$08`, and `$MphfRBNtQM.....`. The first two couldn't be variables as they start with a number, thus, the 6 characters. The third one indeed could be a proper variable, but since it isn't set, it's empty.

Comment: Please add this comment to your answer and I wil accept it..awesome :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code to calculate the string length -

```
echo strlen('$2a$08$MphfRBNtQMLuNro5HOtw3Ovu20cLgC0VKjt6w7zrKXfj1bv8tNnNa');
```

You need to use single quotes, as at the third occurrence of the symbol `$`, a alphabet is starting after it and it get treated as a new variable. So before this third occurrence of `$` only 6 character were there and you were getting string length as 6

Answer (score -2):

Try following

```
<?php

echo strlen('$2a$08$MphfRBNtQMLuNro5HOtw3Ovu20cLgC0VKjt6w7zrKXfj1bv8tNnNa');

?>
```

If you change your string and remove rest of `'$'` signs except the first one, then this will work fine because by adding `$` it gets a special meaning in PHP.

Comment: @Negative Marker, can you please explain the reason?

Comment: Probably because you don't explain what you fixed and why.  The little bit of explanation, "adding `$` it gets a special meaning in PHP", makes no sense.